# select XMLTYPE from Oracle Parse and insert records into another Oracle DB

Tags: python, pandas, xml, elementtree, cx-oracle

I'm using Python for the selecting `XMLTYPE` field from Oracle and parsing into separate fields and insert into another Oracle DB. Below is my code. There are around 300 tags inside the main tag and multiple values for some child tags.

Below are my problems:

1.There are millions of records in the table and its very-very slow. It takes ages to finish.

Please help with better ways of achieving this with python, efficiently without compromising on performance.

My Origin Table:

```
desc cust_test
```

```
Name   Null Type      
------ ---- --------- 
RECID       NUMBER    
RECORD      XMLTYPE()
```

Data:

```
100227  

"<row xml:space="preserve" id="100227">
    <c1>BRENT</c1>
    <c2>BRENT2</c2>
    <c3>Brent3</c3>
    <c4>Brent4</c4>
    <c5>CP</c5>
    <c7>GL</c7>
    <c9>US</c9>
    <c23>1001</c23>
    <c24>26</c24>
    <c25>4</c25>
    <c26>1000</c26>
    <c27>2</c27>
    <c28>US</c28>
    <c29>1</c29>
    <c30>GB</c30>
    <c31>20210315</c31>
    <c42>19581212</c42>
    <c45>1</c45>
    <c48>US0010001</c48>
    <c52>NO</c52>
    <c57>VALUED.CUSTOMER</c57>
    <c58>11</c58>
    <c60>MR</c60>
    <c61>Brent61</c61>
    <c63>MALE</c63>
    <c64>19720915</c64>
    <c68>+12345678</c68>
    <c69>bc@gmail.com</c69>
    <c132>YES</c132>
    <c133>NULL</c133>
    <c134>NULL</c134>
    <c137>NULL</c137>
    <c138>NULL</c138>
    <c149>VALUED.CUSTOMER</c149>
    <c150>11</c150>
    <c151>11</c151>
    <c179/>
    <c179 m="6">NO</c179>
    <c179 m="15">OPT-IN</c179>
    <c179 m="16">20210315</c179>
    <c179 m="176"/>
    <c180>EB.US.ADD.RES.CHAN.AGR}Field ADDRESS/RESIDENCE changed. Still agree?</c180>
    <c180 m="2">KYC/US*41 FROM 10 NOT RECEIVED</c180>
    <c180 m="3">PWM/US*41 FROM 10 NOT RECEIVED</c180>
    <c180 m="4">INTRO/US*41 FROM 10 NOT RECEIVED</c180>
    <c182>2</c182>
    <c183>17338_OFFICER__OFS_SEAT</c183>
    <c184>2104271357</c184>
    <c185>17338_OFFICER_OFS_SEAT</c185>
    <c186>GB0010001</c186>
    <c187>1</c187>
</row>"
```

Python Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import time
import csv
import cx_Oracle
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

con = cx_Oracle.connect('system/Manager@localhost:1521/cdb1')
start = time.time()

SQL = "SELECT RECID,RECORD FROM cust_test2"
#print(SQL)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.prefetchrows = 1000
cur.arraysize = 1000
f = open("D:\Various\myfile21.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
r = cur.execute(SQL)

#col_names = [row[0] for row in cur.description]

#writer.writerow(col_names)
res = cur.fetchall()
for row in res:

   tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(row[1]))
   root = tree.getroot()
   for child in root:
      #print(child.tag, child.text, child.attrib)
      if (child.tag == 'c1') :
         s1 = pd.Series(child.text)
      if (child.tag == 'c3') :
         s3 = pd.Series(child.text)
      if (child.tag == 'c23') :
         s23 = pd.Series(child.text)
      if (child.tag == 'c179') :
         s179 = pd.Series(child.text)
          .......

   df = pd.DataFrame({"c1": s1,
                      "c3": s3,
                      "c23": s23,
                      "c179": s179
                      .......})

   file_name = 'events.csv'
   df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')

   ResultSet_Py_List = []
   ora_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('custom/custom@orcl')
   ora_cursor = ora_conn.cursor()
   my_file = open(file_name, 'r', newline='')

   reader = csv.reader(my_file, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
   row1 = next(reader)
   for index, row in enumerate(reader):
      print(row)
      ResultSet_Py_List.append(row)
   print(str(len(ResultSet_Py_List)) + ' Records from Source')

   sql_insert = """
      INSERT INTO cust_ins (c0,c1,c3,c23,c179,.....) 
      VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,.....)
      """
   ora_cursor.prepare(sql_insert)
   ora_cursor.executemany(None, ResultSet_Py_List)
   ora_conn.commit()

   #writer.writerow(row)
f.close()

elapsed = (time.time() - start)
print(elapsed, "seconds")
```

Comment: I'm glad to see the use of arraysize and executemany!  Regarding XML itself, can you do more processing in the DB with XQUERY?  And then can you use a DB link so data goes directly between databases without having Python in the middle?

Comment: @ChristopherJones..Client is not accepting DBLi,nks.. Also the destination DB can be SQLServer or Postgres... in future... Since the XML is too big, even Oracle parsing takes time.. Tried with queries.. Have not tried with procedure though..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How are multiple tags to be migrated to other table? Why write/read to CSV being overwritten with each iteration? Table design is somewhat questionable with c-named columns. No clearer identifiers?

Comment: @Parfait These are not real data. though i have edited again. Thanks for your edit, I'm new here. I'm not sure how to write to ResultSet_Py_List for inserting other than reading from CSV. Also c columns have diff table with legend. For multiple tags, have to write to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Oracle's [**`XMLTABLE`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) to extract needed values from `XMLTYPE` column. Run such a query from Python and directly pass values from `cursor.fetchall` to `cursor.executemany` between both DB connections. This approach avoids XML parsing, Pandas operations, and CSV write/read steps. Plus, source SQL queries XML data directly on server.

**SQL** *(complete all `c` nodes, adjust data types as needed, save as .sql)*

```sql
SELECT x.c1, x.c2, ..., x.c187
FROM MY_TABLE, 
     XMLTABLE('/row' 
              PASSING XMLTYPE(MY_TABLE.RECORD) 
              COLUMNS c1 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'c1',
                      c2 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'c2',
                      c3 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'c3',
                      ...
                      c187 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'c187'
             ) AS x
```

**Python**

```py
import cx_Oracle

# READ SQL QUERY
with open('/path/to/myquery.sql', mode='r') as f:
    src_sql = f.read()

# SOURCE CONNECTION
src_con = cx_Oracle.connect('system/Manager@localhost:1521/cdb1')
src_cur = src_con.cursor() 
src_cur.prefetchrows = 1000
src_cur.arraysize = 1000

# DESTINATION CONNECTION
dst_con = cx_Oracle.connect('custom/custom@orcl') 
dst_cur = dst_con.cursor()

# APPEND QUERY (MAKE SURE COLUMNS ALIGN TO SOURCE QUERY)
dst_sql = """INSERT INTO cust_ins (c0,c1,c3,c23,c179,.....) 
             VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,.....)""" 

# FETCH SOURCE DATA
src_cur.execute(src_sql)
src_res = src_cur.fetchall()

# APPEND TO DESTINATION TABLE
dst_cur.prepare(dst_sql)
dst_cur.executemany(None, src_res) 
dst_con.commit()

# CLOSE CURSORS AND CONNECTIONS
src_cur.close(); src_con.close()
dst_cur.close(); dst_con.close()
```

Comment: Have implemented your approach and the program takes 30 minutes for processing 1 million records. That's better than what i was doing. Is it possible to improve the performance more, as the table contains 20 million records. Thanks a lot @parfait

Comment: Glad to help. I am not an Oracle expert but look into better indexing and partitioning for large tables. Try running Python local to database server and even dumping parsed XML data to disk like CSV and use bulk importers to other DB. E.g., Oracle's `SQL*Loader`, Postgres's `COPY`, SQL Server' `BULK INSERT`.